# Which mini figure is this?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image: Unknown Lego mini figure]

I would like to know which mini figure this is?

Comment: @mindstormsboi This question is perfectly valid and acceptable in our community, as can be seen by the fact that it is on-topic and has garnered a number of upvotes. I do not find Lotte's rate of posting to be excessive. Furthermore, your comment is rude and does not reflect the values of this community. Please remember to be kind: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/conduct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is [Hoth Rebel Trooper (Orange Chin Dimple)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0259#T=P)

[image]

With missing white [backpack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2524&idColor=1#T=P&C=1) and [goggles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=46304&idColor=1#T=P&C=1).